# Why does ftell doesnt count the number of letters inside a file correctly?

Tags: c, fread, fseek, ftell

I want to count the number of letters inside a file. I've already tried writting the file using Windows and Linux test editors, but both give the same value(7). The file have 5 chars('P','2','\n','#','\n'), why does ftell return the value 7 and not 5?

```
int main(void){
    unsigned char *px=NULL;
        int c=0,size_px;
    FILE *arq;
    arq = fopen("test.txt","rb"); 
        px = (unsigned char*) malloc(100*sizeof(unsigned char));
        fseek(arq,0,SEEK_END); // go to the end of file
        size_px = ftell(arq); //count the letters
        fseek(arq,0,SEEK_SET);  // return to the begin of file
        fread(px,sizeof(unsigned char),size_px,arq);
        printf("|%s| QTY:|%d|",px,size_px);
}
```

Ps: Even if a i change from 'rb' to 'r' mode it continues giving the answear 7, although in the second mode(r) it prints some garbage. The file was saved using Notepad++ as test.txt.
Where there's '\n' it means i pressed the button Enter:

```
P2\n
#\n
```

Comment: Open your file in a hex editor to see what it really contains. (And use `stat` to get a file's size.)

Comment: Note: You're not terminating your string after the read-operation. Nor are you checking the results of `fread()`, which is always a good idea. You may want to fix both of those issues.

Comment: Files don't have letters.  They only have bytes.  You need to do the work to figure out which of those bytes represent letters to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Software applications and operating systems **usually represent a
>   newline with one or two** control characters:
>
> Systems based on ASCII or a compatible character set use either LF
>   (Line feed, '\n', 0x0A, 10 in decimal) or CR (Carriage return, '\r',
>   0x0D, 13 in decimal) individually, **or CR followed by LF (CR+LF,
>   '\r\n', 0x0D0A)**.

Comment: So how can i count how many binary numbers there are on a file mixed with text and binary numbers(pgm image) if i can't count the number of chars correctly from the begin of the file until the last ascii char character(the operational systems will count \n as 1 or \r\n as 2chars)?